# Why Mockito type matchers match unrelated objects?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, matcher

I need a behaviour of a mock to depend on argument type.
I've tried to use `Matchers.any(Class<>)` to provide two behaviours:

```
public class MockitoTest {
    public interface ToMock {
        String accept(Object object);
    }
    interface A {
    }
    interface B {
    }
    @Test
    public void doAnswer() {
        ToMock mock = Mockito.mock(ToMock.class);

        Mockito.doReturn("A received").when(mock).accept(Matchers.any(A.class));
        Mockito.doReturn("B received").when(mock).accept(Matchers.any(B.class));

        Assert.assertEquals("A received", mock.accept(new A() {}));
        Assert.assertEquals("B received", mock.accept(new B() {}));
    }
}
```

Test fails with:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[A] received> but was:<[B] received>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Mockito version 1.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. According to the documentation of [`Matchers.any(Class)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class))

> Any kind object, not necessary of the given class. The class argument is provided only to avoid casting.

Comment: I'm surprised documentation does not reference [isA](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)), which does exactly what I need.

Comment: [Latest version of Mockito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-)  has changed this matcher to check argument type.